# Simple MySQL Insert doesn't work?

Tags: php, mysql

I have the strangest problem. I wrote this very simple `INSERT` query:

```
if(isset($_POST['putUser'])) {
    $user = $_POST['user'];
    $amount = $_POST['amount'];
    $what = $_POST['what'];
    $country = $_POST['country'];
    $platform = $_POST['platform'];

    $query = mysql_query('INSERT INTO sells(id, user, amount, what, country, platform) VALUES (NULL , '.$user.', 1, 1, 1, 1)');
    if($query) {
        echo 'ok';
    } else {
        die(mysql_error());
    }
}
```

And it doesn't work. It works when I pust `1` in all values instead of, as in the example, `$user`. But when the variables are present, it throws an error `Unknown column 'Test username' in 'field list'`. Where's my mistake?

Comment: Inb4 copypasta telling you how bad you are for using the `mysql_` functions.

Comment: You shouldn't use [mysql.*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) function as they are deprecated and unsafe. Use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) instead.

Comment: @Cobra_Fast: here it goes ^

Comment: @Cobra_Fast - And then another one about [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://cz1.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).

Comment: Please, before you write **any** more SQL interfacing code, you must read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) to avoid severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Also, `mysql_query` should not be used in new applications. It's a deprecated interface that's being removed from future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and will make your database code easier to get right.

Comment: @AmalMurali and there is number two ^

Comment: @Cobra_Fast Well, as long as there's no close question reason that's `Another SQL injection using mysql_*`, people will point SQL injections out. Shouldn't they?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson what does the interface you choose have to do with vulnerability? Nothing. If you have clean and secure code the interface shouldn't matter at all.

Comment: @Cobra_Fast I've not claimed that the interface is insecure in itself, but judging from the sheer amount of PHP/mysql_* questions that have injections, it would seem non obvious to use correctly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

well the value you have passed to the query is not enclosed inside quotes. when you don't enclose a string inside quotes mysql assumes it's a field name. Also you have forgotten to escape your string.

```
$query = mysql_query('INSERT INTO sells (id, user, amount, what, country, platform) '
      . 'VALUES (NULL , "' . mysql_real_escape_string($user) . '", 1, 1, 1, 1)');
```

Finally you should migrate away from using `mysql` extension and use `pdo` or `mysqli` instead.

Comment: +1 This answers the OP question, and shows the right way for a string to be included in SQL text, wrapping it in a call to the mysql_real_escape_string function.

Answer (score 6):

You'r inserting field user(string) as non string try this:

```
if(isset($_POST['putUser'])) {
    $user = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user']);
    $amount = $_POST['amount'];
    $what = $_POST['what'];
    $country = $_POST['country'];
    $platform = $_POST['platform'];

    $query = mysql_query('INSERT INTO sells(id, user, amount, what, country, platform) VALUES (NULL , "'.$user.'", 1, 1, 1, 1)');
    if($query) {
        echo 'ok';
    } else {
        die(mysql_error());
    }
}
```

As everybody say on comments, you shouldn't use the post info direct on mysql query, this make "sql injection atack" the easyiest thing on the world. You should scape some characters from string to prevent this. And do some research about PDO on PHP this link may help [here](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php)

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Or don't use mysql at all... mysqli or PDO.

Comment: Focus on question, the question don't is "how i can make this more secure or how prevent sql injection atack or something else" the question is: "why this won't work?" the answer is "ur putting string as non string." have many other things on the code to adjust. but isn't the question right now.

Comment: The nature of the question doesn't matter. Do it **correctly**. The answer you provide should not be this bad.

Comment: So i'll ask any bannal thing about a code, and you guys will point all wrong things on the code and correct to me? LOL, why i do my work if i have u guys?

Comment: This is not a trivial issue. This is a severe security problem, but more, without escaping, usernames like `O'Malley` wouldn't work, so your answer would be incorrect anyway.

Comment: To be honest there is SO much wrong with the original code that you'd have to spend an hour fixing it in the answer, by which time the question will have been answered by something short, pithy and equally wrong and the whole thing will have dropped to page 2 or 3 never to be seen again.

Comment: By all means, provide an answer to the question: "string literals need to be enclosed in quotes in SQL text". But if you are going to post actual code, which the OP is going to copy, then you could take the opportunity to show an example of the (should be *required*) call to the `mysql_real_escape_string` function. (Given the question that OP is asking, it would appear he's *never* created SQL statement that inserts string values before, and showing him an example subject to SQL Injection vulnerabilities is NOT doing him a favor.

Comment: @CD001: let me get this straight. Are you suggesting that a bad answer posted on StackOverflow is justified because other people post a lot of bad answers? Posting an equally bad answer along with a bunch of other bad answers is okay because it will never be seen again? Did I get that right?

Comment: I think ppl have mutch rush to post an answer and don't have time to improve it on the best form

Comment: @CD001: And I don't see SO much wrong with the original code. I see a problem with a string not enclosed in quotes in the SQL. Once the OP fixes that problem (following the pattern shown in this answer), he's going to be oblivious to the fact that he's introduced a SQL Injection vulnerability. How is that helping the OP? How does that help anyone else who searches StackOverflow and finds this answer?

Comment: @Spencer7592 : No - I'm just not sure it's worth posting an answer that goes far beyond the scope of the question; the answer given explicitly answers the question asked, nothing more, nothing less. Shall I post an answer that breaks down everything I can see wrong with the original code (at a glance) to demonstrate?

Comment: @CD001: see the answer from DevZerO. That's the right answer to this question.

Comment: @spencer7593 : true enough, but it doesn't solve the other myriad problems with the script and it proves my point about it not being worth going beyond the scope of the original question... and if that code is used on a live website it would be very easy to make it fall over completely.

Comment: @CD001: Let me see if I understand you. Because other code would make it "very easy to make it fall over completely", that *justifies* providing a wrong answer? You say an answer should be "nothing more, nothing less". Well I say that the proposed code in this answer is in fact "less" than an answer to the question the OP asked. Ask this about that same line of code that was modified: does this contain a mistake? The answer is: yes it does. But you advocate that replacing "wrong" code with other "wrong" code is considered adequate, and superior to answer that has code that is right.

Comment: @spencer7593 : not really, I upvoted DevZerO's answer, not this one as his answer was **more** correct. This answer is only wrong insofar as it doesn't escape strings like `O'Reilly` so will break in those instances but it does, however, pinpoint exactly where the problem lies and shows how to fix it - albeit only partially whilst leaving the code open to SQL injections. If you want a "right" answer, where do you stop? Do you point out that only 'putUser' is being tested for existence and that a form could be crafted to leave the rest out? And so on...

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the string in quotes:

```
$query = mysql_query('INSERT INTO sells(id, user, amount, what, country, platform) VALUES (NULL , "'.$user.'", 1, 1, 1, 1)');
```

Comment: **No.** Slapping quotes on an otherwise hazardously bad query does not fix it.

Comment: Yes it does, that query will work. The OP wasn't asking about prevention of SQLi and user input sanitisation. Thanks for the down vote...

Comment: You can't write code like this and expect it to magically work. `mysql_real_escape_string` is **required** if you're using `mysql_query`. No exceptions. No excuses. It doesn't matter if it wasn't part of the original question, it's not a valid answer without it, and the way you phrased it, quotes was the *only* problem, which it is not. That you think this query "will work" speaks to how casually the PHP community treats SQL injection bugs. Don't complain about down-votes when you can fix the problem in seconds.

Comment: @spencer7593 That's not what the OP asked. Besides, if you're being that picky he shouldn't be using mysql_real_escape_string as it's deprecated. Is this how you write your code?

Comment: @tadman Where is it documented that mysql_real_escape_string is required? Please show me.

Comment: @Scott Helme: But that is *EXACTLY* what the OP asked. "**What's my mistake?**" The mistake he made is an improperly constructed SQL statement. Your answer has the *same* mistake: an improperly constructed SQL statement. Is this how I write my code? Not like the line in your answer, no. Back before the mysqli_ and PDO interfaces were available, we used the `mysql_real_escape_string` function because that's the function that was available from the MySQL client library.

Comment: "**Where is it documented that mysql_real_escape_string is required?**" @Scott Helme: It's documented here in the PHP manual: [http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) **`This function must always (with few exceptions) be used to make data safe before sending a query to MySQL.`**

Comment: "**If you're being *that picky* he shouldn't be using mysql_real_escape_string as it's deprecated.**" @Scott Helme: as long as the code is using the `mysql_ ` interface, then the code should be using `mysql_real_escape_string`. Yes, the mysql_real_escape_string function is deprecated, but its not just the one function, its the entire interface. And I am going to be **that picky about it**. The fact the interface is *deprecated* does not mean that we should abandon best practice and recommend bad code. There's still plenty of production code that's using the `mysql_` interface successfully.